# Numerical method for mixed system of equations and nonlinear inequalities

Tags: root-systems, approximation-algorithms, applied-mathematics, mixing, numerical-systems

I am currently encountering challenges in determining the solution method for the following system of equations and inequalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&F(x) = 0\\
&G(x) < 0\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and the functions $F_i$ and $G_i$ can have the forms $A_{i}x+B_i$ or $x^{T}Q_{i}x+P_{i}x+K_i.$

For example, the single inequality $G_i(x) < 0$ will be equivalent to $H_i(x, a_i) = G_i(x) + a_i = 0$, where $a_i > 0$. In that case, the system can be transformed into the general form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&F(x) = 0\\
&H(x,a) = 0\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ and $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m) > 0$.

In order to solve this system, I have considered the Newton-Raphson method, but an application of this method seems infeasible. Can you suggest any other approach?

Comment: The question, as posed, is way too general to expect a meaningful discussion. Can you specify your $F$ and $G$?

Comment: Hi @fedja, there are no specific cases for $F$ and $G$. As you can see, with the Newton-Raphson method, it can solve the general problem of $F = 0$, and in my approach, I only add the condition that some components of $x > 0$.

Comment: But if you want a specific case, the functions $F_i$ and $G_i$ can have the forms $A_{i}x + B_i$ or $x^{T}Q_{i}x + P_{i}x + K_{i}$.

Comment: @AnNam: you should edit the post to specify the $F_i$ and $G_i$ are of this form. With that information, the question becomes sensible.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Thank you for your reminder!

Comment: You may like to try specialized software such as [RAGlib](https://www-polsys.lip6.fr/~safey/RAGLib/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would like a specific algorithm.